# Prevent keyboard messages from reaching application

Tags: excel, winapi, ms-office, hook

I am working on application that automates Excel via com. 
The problem I am having is that sometimes when user presses some keyboard buttons 
the Excel steals the focus and goes into Cell Edit state which causes my application to crash.
What can be the best way to prevent keyboard messages from reaching Excel.
I tried unsuccessfully CBT hook and GetMessage hook. Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel 2010's Application object has an `Interactive` property. Set it to false and Excel will block all keyboard and mouse input except for any dialog boxes you display.

```
Application.Interactive = False
```

I'm not sure when `Interactive` was added but I don't think it existed in Excel 2000.

Comment: This is great idea! Never thought about googling for it. It was added in Excel 2007

Comment: @SparcU, you might also want to use `Application.Cursor = xlWait` to change the mouse pointer to an hourglass. Just don't forget to set it back to `xlDefault` when done.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way perhaps is to use [BlockInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx), which blocks both mouse and keyboard input across the entire desktop: this is useful if you want to block out the user just for a short period of time.

Alternatively, if you just want to block input from reaching a specific exe, use [SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, ...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) - per MSDN, you can return -1 from the hookproc to cause the input to be ignored:

> If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, [...] If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

One nice feature of WH_KEYBOARD_LL hooks is that they don't require a separate DLL, you can do everything in your own EXE. But only use it against the threadID of the excel app; if you have the HWND of the app, use GetWindowThreadID() to get that.

Comment: WH_KEYBOARD_LL does not work with local hooks. Only global. So when I install it it slows down everything on the computer

Comment: This is a good idea.  WH_KEYBOARD hook with DLL solved my problem